# Not able to connect Django with mongoDb

Tags: python, django, mongodb, backend, djongo

I am using djongo to connect my mongodb with django. the mongodb i use is atlas service.my password and username are correct even though its showing auth failed.

```
System check identified some issues: 
    sock_info.check_auth(all_credentials)
  File "C:\Users\rupek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 712, in check_auth
    auth.authenticate(credentials, self)
  File "C:\Users\rupek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pymongo\auth.py", line 564, in authenticate
    auth_func(credentials, sock_info)
  File "C:\Users\rupek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pymongo\auth.py", line 263, in _authenticate_scram
    res = sock_info.command(source, cmd)
  File "C:\Users\rupek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 603, in command
    return command(self.sock, dbname, spec, slave_ok,
  File "C:\Users\rupek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pymongo\network.py", line 165, in command
    helpers._check_command_response(
  File "C:\Users\rupek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pymongo\helpers.py", line 159, in _check_command_response
    raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Authentication failed.
```

My setting.py file

```
'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': 'first',
        'ENFORCE_SCHEMA': False,
        'CLIENT': {
            'host': 'mongodb+srv://user:pass@cluster0-omtoq.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
            'port': 27017,
            'username': 'user',
            'password': 'pass',
            'authSource': 'first',
            'authMechanism': 'SCRAM-SHA-1'
        },
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you whitelisted the ip of the machine where django is running?

Comment: Yes i added the ip

Comment: Then, I don't know. sorry.

Comment: Did you create a custom authSource named "first"?

Comment: No, i dont know what it is, how to create that?